# Binary heap: prove that number of nodes of height h is not bigger than $\lceil \frac{n}{2^{h+1}} \rceil$

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, binary-trees

My thoughts process: let number of elements in heap be $n$, total height of binary heap be $H$, height of node be $h$, and let number of nodes with height $h$ be $x$.

Then number of nodes with height $H-1 \le 2^1, H-2 \le 2^2, ... => x \le 2^{H-h} = 2^{\lfloor \lg n \rfloor - h} = \frac{2^{\lfloor \lg n \rfloor }}{2^h}$

However, I don't see how this can be transformed to $\lceil \frac{n}{2^{h+1}} \rceil$, as $n/2$ is less than $2^{\lfloor \lg n \rfloor }$

Comment: Is this a binary heap with just the usual heap invariant or does it also have some balance constraints that it has to satisfy as well? For example, I can create a degenerate heap that's just a list that nevertheless satisfies the heap invariant (namely, that the children must be smaller than the parent).

Comment: @LeeGao, it is book question, I suppose it is usual binary heap, as there was nothing about balancing in this chapter

Comment: @LeeGao According to wikipedia, a [binary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) is defined to have the property of a complete binary tree (All levels except possible the lowest one are fully filled, and the lowest level is filled from left to right).

Comment: I wasn't aware that this is the standard definition. I was taught that binary heaps should satisfy the shape property, but that it isn't always required.

Comment: If it's from a book, can you give the citation to the book where it appears and the chapter & exercise number?  There's a chance it might help others to look up the context there (e.g., how that book defines binary heap), if they have a copy too.

Comment: @D.W. **Introduction to Algorithms**  by Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson - task 7.3.3

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the information in the question?  We want questions to be self-contained (comments exist only to help you improve the question).  Thank you!

Comment: Would someone please explain me how is it possible to have $H-1\le2^1$? .Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$n$ element tree has depth $\lceil{\log_2n}\rceil-1$. If $h$ is the height of nodes in any $n$ element heap from leaves then the nodes are situated at the depth of $\lceil{\log_2n}\rceil-1-h$ from the root.

Now, at most $2^{\lceil{\log_2n}\rceil-1-h} = \lceil{\frac{n}{2^{h+1}}}\rceil$ nodes/leaves are possible with $\lceil{\log_2n}\rceil-1-h$ depth in a heap.

Note that depth is the number of edges from the root & height is the number of edges from the highest level in a heap.

Comment: consiser heap... n=4
when height is 0 ceil(n/2)=2 (upper bound is fine)
when height is 1 ceil(n/4)=1  (here the upper bound is not correct)
when height is 2 ceil(n/8)=1 (here it is correct)

consider this heap... n=5
when height is 0 ceil(n/2)=3 (upper bound is fine)
when height is 1 ceil(n/4)=2  (here the upper bound is correct)
when height is 2 ceil(n/8)=1 (here it is correct)

please explain me why is it so??

have I made any mistake in understanding the theorem statement??

Comment: Could you please explain why is depth of tree $\lceil \lg n\rceil-1$ while I read and proved $\lfloor \lg n \rfloor$ ?

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Ain't both expressions same?

Comment: Well how, I am confused on that. Please explain. Thank you. I know that $\lfloor x \rfloor \le x \le \lceil x \rceil $