# Difficulty understanding the solution of heap problem in CLRS book?

Tags: binary-trees, heaps

I am reading [the solution](http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/%7Eajl213/CLRS/Ch6.pdf) of this problem in CLRS:

> Show that there are at most $\lceil {n/2^{h+1}} \rceil$ nodes of height $h$ in any $n$-element heap.
>
> **Solution**: All the nodes of height $h$ partition the set of leaves into sets of size between $2^{h-1}$ and $2^h$, where all but one is size $2^h$. Just by putting all the children of each in their own part of the partition. Recal from 6.1-2 that the heap has height $\lfloor\lg(n)\rfloor$, so, by looking at the one element of this height (the root), we get that there are at most $2^{\lfloor\lg(n)\rfloor}$ leaves. Since each of the vertices of height $h$ partitions this into parts of size at least $2^{h-1}+1$, and all but one corresponds to a part of size $2^h$, we can let $k$ denote the quantity we wish to bound,  so,
>
> $$(k-1)2^h + k(2^{h-1}+1) \leq 2^{\lfloor\lg (n)\rfloor}$$
> so
> $$k\leq \frac{n+2^h}{2^{h+1}+2^h+1} \leq \frac{n}{2^{h+1}}\leq \left\lceil\frac{n}{2^{h+1}}\right\rceil$$

But I don't understand how to come up with the fact that $(k-1)2^h + k(2^{h-1} + 1)$ is less than the number of leaves.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't understand the how to come up with the fact that $(k−1)2^h+k(2^{h−1}+1)$ is less than the number of leaves.

It is quite straightforward from the very first statement of the solution which says there are all but *one set* of size $2^{h}$. Where $k$ is total number of sets of nodes at height $h$.

Therefore, total number of nodes at $h$ height is:
$$\begin{align*}
s &= (\text{total sets} \times \text{size of each sets})\\
 &= k(2^{h}+2^{h-1}+1)-1 \cdot 2^{h}\\
 &= (k−1)2^h+k(2^{h−1}+1)
\end{align*}$$

---

Another way to solve this is [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66098/binary-heap-prove-that-number-of-nodes-of-height-h-is-not-bigger-than-lceil/107090#107090).

Comment: Can you elaborate more. I still can't get it.

Comment: I think the number of leaves will be $(k-1)2^h$ plus some numbers.

Comment: My supposed solution is this. Can you check if it is true.

Comment: @toantruong It is $k[(2^h)+(2^{h-1}+1)]-1*2^h$

Comment: I still don't get this formula. If we have a full binary tree with height $2$, and we compute the number of nodes with height $1$, so in this case $k = 2$. If I apply your formula, we will have $k[2^h + (2^{h-1}+1)] - 2^h = 6$, but in this case, the heap has only $4$ leaves.

Comment: @toantruong It's correct. $h$ is height from the leaves, not root. If you have $h=1$, then definitely the equation is less than or equal to $2^{lgn}$. check again.

Comment: @toantruong Check other linked solution for the same question as well.

Comment: @mr-sigma Can you explain to me about this line. Since each of the vertices of height $h$ partitions this into parts of size at least $2h−1+1$, and all but one corresponds to a part of size $2h$.

Comment: @mr-sigma Also, can you apply your formula in the case of full tree with height 2?

Comment: @toantruong Yeah, it will work and sorry I have edited the question now. there were some typos earlier.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the question is this. Can you check if there is any flaw in this solution.

> All but one of the node with height $h$ are full binary tree, so the number of leaves in these trees are $2^h$. The other one will have at least one leave. So the number of leaves is at least $(k-1)2^h + 1$ and it is bounded by $\frac{n}{2}$. So we have $(k-1)2^h + 1 \leqslant \frac{n}{2}$. From that, we can derive that $k \leqslant 1 + \frac{n}{2^{h+1}} - \frac{1}{2^h} \leqslant 1 + \frac{n}{2^{h+1}}$. So we have $k \leqslant \lceil \frac{n}{2^{h+1}} \rceil$