# How to solve the following equation: $(k-1)2^h + k(2^{h-1}+1) \leq 2^{\lfloor\lg (n)\rfloor}$?

Tags: heaps

I came with this interesting question and could understand how did we get to this equation:
$(k-1)2^h + k(2^{h-1}+1) \leq 2^{\lfloor\lg (n)\rfloor}$

But in the next step, it reached to the following step which I cannot understand. Please help me out in understanding this:

$k\leq \frac{n+2^h}{2^{h+1}+2^h+1} \leq \frac{n}{2^{h+1}}\leq \left\lceil\frac{n}{2^{h+1}}\right\rceil$
Reference: Problem 6.3.3, CLRS. [Difficulty understanding the solution of heap problem in CLRS book?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/107077/difficulty-understanding-the-solution-of-heap-problem-in-clrs-book)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting, let me note that there seems to be an "off by 1" issue with the way that height is measured. It seems that you should replace $h$ throughout with $h+1$.

First of all, let us notice that $2^{\lfloor \lg n \rfloor} \leq 2^{\lg n} \leq n$.
Therefore
$$
(k-1)2^h + k(2^{h-1} + 1) \leq n.
$$
Next, notice that
$$
(k-1)2^h + k(2^{h-1} + 1) = k(2^h + 2^{h-1} + 1) - 2^h.
$$
Therefore
$$
k(2^h + 2^{h-1} + 1) \leq n + 2^h.
$$
This immediately implies that
$$
k \leq \frac{n + 2^h}{2^h + 2^{h-1} + 1} \leq \frac{n + 2^h}{2^h + 2^{h-1}} = \frac{n + 2^h}{(3/2)2^h}.
$$

Now, $h + 1 = \lfloor \lg n \rfloor \le \lg n$, and so $2^{h+1} \leq n$, implying $2^h \leq n/2$. Therefore
$$
k \leq \frac{n+2^h}{(3/2)2^h} \leq \frac{n+n/2}{(3/2)2^h} = \frac{(3/2)n}{(3/2)2^h} = \frac{n}{2^h} \leq \left\lceil \frac{n}{2^h} \right\rceil.
$$

Comment: Could you please let me know on that **off by 1** issue?

Comment: It seems that you should replace ℎ throughout with ℎ+1.

Comment: But why so? if you don't mind me elaborating that a bit please.

Comment: It all depends how you measure height. I suspect that the first inequality measures height one way, and the other inequalities measure it another way.

Comment: Height is the length of the longest root-to-leaf path. You can measure length either as number of vertices or as number of edges. The two measures differ by 1. This might be what is going on here.

Comment: As you can see, if you take your first inequality, we don't get your other inequalities; we do get them if we switch $h$ and $h+1$.

Comment: By the first inequality you mean: $(k-1)2^h + k(2^{h-1}+1) \leq 2^{\lfloor\lg (n)\rfloor}$?

Comment: That's right. It's your premise. The other inequalities are the conclusions you want to draw from the premise.

Comment: I am sorry on asking you the stupid question but please could you explain me how are we not able to prove the inequality using $2^h$. Please help me out. thank you.

Comment: I just gave you the derivation. If you start with your premise, you don't get you conclusion. But curiously, you get the exact same expression but with $h$ replaced with $h-1$. I don't think it's a coincidence.

Comment: $h-1$ or $h+1$?

Comment: Anyways I partially understood the answer except the h+1 part. I understood the significance but cannot understand on how to present this in an answer. Thank you for reaching out and answering the question :)

Comment: The pair $(h,h-1)$ is the same as the pair $(h+1,h)$. It depends on your point of view.

Comment: As to how to present it in an answer, in an answer you should be consistent, using $h$ for one and the same thing. So this problem should not occur.

Comment: Sure. Thank you so much. Please upvote the question if you think it was concise and feasible enough to be posted here. Because I do not have any other options except clearing my doubts here, I am afraid if CS network would not allow me to ask any more questions if I do not get response Or upvotes.

Comment: Hi there. One last question please if you do not mind me asking you. How did we get to $\frac{(3/2)n}{(3/2)2^h}$?

Comment: I added some more details. However, I should warn you that the ability to carry out such algebraic manipulations is necessary to succeed in your class. During the exam I won't be available to point out each and every small step.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm sorry. I will take a note of that from the next time