# Proving $\lceil \lg n \rceil -1 = \lfloor \lg n \rfloor$

Tags: algorithms, heap-sort

I recently came across the question:

Show that there are at most $\lceil n / 2^{h + 1} \rceil$ nodes of height hh in any nn-element heap.

I looked for some solutions and found this one:
[Binary heap: prove that number of nodes of height h is not bigger than $\lceil \frac{n}{2^{h+1}} \rceil$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66098/binary-heap-prove-that-number-of-nodes-of-height-h-is-not-bigger-than-lceil)

But I got confused with the answer which used the expression:
$$\lceil{\log_2n}\rceil-1$$
as the height of the tree.

But, I am confused because I have earlier proved that the height of the tree is:

$$\lfloor \lg n \rfloor$$

Even if I consider both are the same it could only be true if $\lg n$ returns a decimal value instead of an integer.

For example, consider an example of taking $n=4$ the example would fail as:

$$\lfloor \lg n \rfloor \le \lg n \le  \lceil \lg n  \rceil$$

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Might be an off-by-one issue, that is, one of the $n$ should be $n+1$ or $n-1$.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get you. Could you please explain?

Comment: For example, I believe that $\lfloor \log_2 n \rfloor = \lceil \log_2 (n+1) \rceil - 1$ (unless $n$ is very small).

Comment: Yeah but doesn't this mean that the answer : https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/107090/85651 is wrong?

Comment: Well I do agree on this.

Comment: I wouldn't worry so much about such small inaccuracies.

Comment: Well I wish having a method proving it with $\lfloor \lg n \rfloor$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $\lceil \log_2 n \rceil - 1$ for the height of a $n$-element heap is wrong.
For $n=1$ the expression yields $-1$ instead of $0$, for $n=2$ it yields $0$ instead of $1$, etc...

In general, for $i \in \mathbb{N}^+$, an heap with $2^i$ nodes has height $i$ but $\lceil \log_2 2^i \rceil - 1 = i-1$.

The equality $\lceil \log_2n \rceil -1=\lfloor \log_2 n\rfloor$ is also wrong, as it can be seen by picking $n=2^i$ for any $i \in \mathbb{N}^+$.

Comment: But does it mean that the answer in the link is wrong? https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/107090/85651

Comment: Formally, yes.$\phantom{}$